# Google spreadsheet mobile app doesn't show custom made functionalities

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile, google-sheets-api

I have written Apps Script code for Google Spreadsheet to serve my personal purpose. I learnt from Google site that custom made things to show up in Google Spreadsheets mobile app it has to be published as add-on. Do we have to go only in this route to get my custom made functionality in google spreadsheet mobile app?

EDIT: I have to clarify my question, actually I have created custom menus to call custom functions in google spreadsheet. These custom menus are not shown in the google spreadsheet mobile app. This is my requirement.

Apology for not asking question clearly.

Comment: You may refer with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104486/google-spreadsheet-custom-menus-are-not-displayed-for-anonymous-users) which stated that in order for Scripts to run on a Google Sheet, the user must be logged in and have "can edit" rights. This means that anonymous users will not be able to run a Script. You may also check this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/dkmoAReitvY/UtP-EFRpEgAJ) for more information.

Comment: @abielita thanks for your reply. Link you have shared doesn't talk about google spreadsheet mobile app

Answer (score 0):

No. Your understanding is wrong. As long as your custom function has been put in the script editor of that spreadsheet, it will work in Google sheets mobile app as a custom function. But it won't show the function name or syntax in the list of functions. But it works.

Comment: See the revised question; it's not about custom functions.